# My activity_main.xml is not showing my contacts

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, contacts

In my Android Studio layout file for my MainActivity class, there is a layout that used to show my contacts but it doesn't work anymore.

This is how the layout shows:

[image: activity_main.xml]

This is what shows in the emulator (note: I already have added contacts).

[image: Outcome]

I'm not sure if it has to do with the layout, the MainActivity itself or the Manifest.

The `onCreate` code that's suppose to show contacts below the buttons:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

ContactModel dummy = new ContactModel();
dummy.setName("foo");
dummy.setNumber("123");
arrayList.add(dummy);

adapter = new MainAdapter(this, arrayList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

Button add_btn = findViewById(R.id.add_btn);

add_btn.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Add_Contact.class)));

Button rem_btn = findViewById(R.id.rem_btn);

rem_btn.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main_Remove_Contact.class)));
}
```

This is what my `ContactModel` looks like:

```
package com.app.wolfix;

public class ContactModel {
    String name, number;

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String getNumber() { return number; }

    public void setNumber(String number) { this.number = number; }
}
```

Please don't hesitate to ask for any piece of code necessary, I will edit the question if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you setting the adapter for the RecyclerView? (usually something like `rv.setAdapter(myAdapter);` in your MainActivity)

Comment: I'll add the MainActivity code later today.

Comment: It's been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here (in the original version of the question):

- You never actually created an instance of your adapter
- You never assigned it to the RecyclerView
- You never added any data to `arrayList`
- You never set a layout manager for the RecyclerView.

Putting all of these together, the following `onCreate` works for me with your example to show dummy items in the list. You will need to add your actual code for populating `arrayList` somewhere in there still.

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    ContactModel dummy = new ContactModel();
    dummy.setName("foo");
    dummy.setNumber("123");
    arrayList.add(dummy);

    adapter = new MainAdapter(this, arrayList);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // in your code, you could call something here to populate
    // arrayList with real values
}
```

Comment: How would I go as to add content to my ```arrayList``` in my ```getContactList``` method. I want contacts to be added. So is there a way I can give them their own ID or primary key or would I need a database to do that?

Comment: I have no idea what `ContactModel` is, but you would create one of those and then add it to the array list (e.g. `arrayList.add(someContact)`)

Comment: Actually I have the "content", if by content you mean contacts. There's three in the built-in contact list on the phone, it's suppose to show it in activity_main.xml. The problem is, it's not reading it. So isn't the recyclerView having some problem in this layout. I'll add the activity_main.xml code.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's on the phone - you never add it to the `arrayList` that you are showing in the RecyclerView, so the RecyclerView has nothing to display. It is up to you, in your code, to populate *what* you want to show (`arrayList`) and define *how* you want to translate that data to the display (what your adapter does).

Comment: If you want to do a test, instead of calling `checkPermission` just try adding some dummy contacts to `arrayList` in `onCreate` to see if they are displayed.

Comment: Alright, I'll get back to on that once I get some results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242686/discussion-between-andre-almeida-and-tyler-v).

Comment: Alright, thanks, it worked! But I will still have to figure out how to add my contactList there.